# How to compute the sectional curvature of a hypersurface

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Consider the surface in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$
$$H=\left\{(x^1,\cdots,x^{n+1})\in\mathbb R^{n+1}\mid\sum_{i=1}^n(x^i)^2-(x^{n+1})^2=-1,x^{n+1}>0\right\}$$
Prove that the tensor field

$$h=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathrm dx^i\otimes\mathrm dx^i-\mathrm dx^{n+1}\otimes\mathrm dx^{n+1}$$
restricted to $H$ is a Riemann metric, and compute the sectional curvature.

I tried to use the coordinate $(u_1,\cdots,u_n,\sqrt{1+u_1^2+\cdots+u_n^2})$ to prove $h\vert_H$ is positive definite, but it is too difficult to compute curvature. Please help me.

Comment: It is Minkowski metric on hyperboloid model. How about you calculate the  Guassian curvature for $n=2$ first? Then try higer dimension by calculating the shape operator $S\partial_i=-\nabla_{\partial_i}N$, you can also find something useful at page 38 (hyperboloid model) and page 148 (calculating curvature) in Riemannian manifold: An introduction to curvature by John M. Lee

Comment: Thanks a lot, the material you gave are very helpful.